# Statistical models or problems equipped with methods that guarantee optimal or near solutions in finite time

Tags: optimization, modeling, computational-statistics

What are some statistical models or problems that have computationally tractable solutions and are guaranteed to be optimal or near optimal? By computationally tractable, I mean finite time and practical time.

For example, a linear model can be fit by computing matrix inverses or optimized via gradient descent.

Similarly, in the simplest multi-armed bandit problems, the upper confidence bound sampling method yields (near) optimal regret bounds.

Examples of models and problems that don't come with guarantees in finite time:

1. neural networks (non-convex optimization)
2. high-dimensional integration, e.g., intractable sums due to combinatorial structures, Markov chain Monte Carlo requires infinite time